# Replacing all instances of newlines not inside tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a body of text with newlines in it, and I would like to replace all instances of newlines that are *not inside certain tags* with `<br />`s. The tags are `[something][~something]`, where `something` could be anything.

Sorry for not including what I have already tried, but I have no idea how to get a regex to match something not inside something else. Is that even possible?

Comment: It would help if you post a sample of the html you're trying to replace.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While remembering that you should not parse XML/HTML with a regex and this is an instance of that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#

$in = "foo\nbar\nbaz[something]else\nis\n[~something]\nHappening\n[something]else\nis\n[~something]here\n";
$out = "";

while ($in =~ s/^(.*?)(\[something\].*?\[~something\])//s)
{
  my($before,$during) = ($1,$2);
  $before =~ s/\n/<br \/>/g;
  $out .= $before.$during;
}
$in =~ s/\n/<br \/>/g;
$out .= $in;
print $out;
```

Yes, not in your language of choice, but the concept (parsing the data in stages stuff before your tags and stuff inside your tags while deleting the processed data) should be portable.

Comment: utterly useless to post perl here for php

Comment: Actually Perl is my language of choice but I am forced to use PHP. And thanks, works like a charm, I hope I can port it to PHP and everything.

Comment: It is not "utterly useless" to post perl here.  The user was asking a regex based question and preg_match is implementing Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE)  PHP shares much similarity to Perl.